# Cannot use positional argument after named argument in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminPanel\HomeController as AdminHomeController;

Route::post(uri:'save',[HomeController::class,'save']);
Route::get(uri:'/admin',[AdminHomeController::class, 'index']);
```

Why can't i use this parameters ? Why am i getting this error i have no idea.

Comment: If you're going to name one parameter, you should name all of them as you pass them in

Comment: @ADyson so i change App\Http\Controllers\HomeController as HomeController but it's not working.

Comment: [edit] the question please, to add precisely what you tried and what the error message is now.

Comment: @ADyson error message is still same after i deleted name(name:'save')

Comment: It's the second parameters to the post and get functions which aren't named, that's the problem. Nothing to do with  the "name" function (not really sure how you came to that conclusion). Can you see - you've named the "uri" parameter, but not the one which comes after it. Either name them all, or none

Answer (score 1):

Good old-fashioned positional parameters are identified by, well, their position. On the other side, named parameters can be shuffled because its their name what defines what they are:

```
function foo($a, $b) {
    var_dump($a, $b);
}
foo(10, 20);
foo(b: 20, a: 10);
```

Both calls print the same result:

```
int(10)
int(20)
```

However, if you mix them, there's no way to reliably determine what parameters you mean:

```
foo(b: 20, 10); // Is 10 the second parameter ($b)?
```

Yes, PHP could have implemented complex rules to resolve any ambiguity, but that would be unlikely to enhance code readability.

So... you need to pick one: named or positional.

Comment: I understand what you told me but i can't implement it in my code.Can you clarify it ?

Comment: I don't know anything about Laravel, but I have the impression that you aren't using named parameters for any particular reason. Don't use them and you should be good.